# Select columns which contains a string in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a **pyspark dataframe** with a lot of columns, and I want to select the ones which contain a certain string, and others. For example:

```
df.columns = ['hello_world','hello_country','hello_everyone','byebye','ciao','index']
```

I want to select the ones which contains **'hello'** and also the column named **'index'**, so the result will be:

```
['hello_world','hello_country','hello_everyone','index']
```

I want something like `df.select('hello*','index')`

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

I found a quick way to solve it, so I answered myself, **Q&A** style. If someone sees my solution and can provide a better one I will appreciate it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found a quick and elegant way:

```
selected = [s for s in df.columns if 'hello' in s]+['index']
df.select(selected)
```

With this solution i can add more columns I want without editing the for loop that *Ali AzG* suggested.

Comment: Great solution. and do not need `*` before `selected`?

Comment: Thanks ! I don't :)

Comment: You can take it one step further  You can keep it all in the one line, like this:
`selected = df.select([s for s in df.columns if 'hello' in s]+['index'])`.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try to use [colRegex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex) function introduced in Spark 2.3, where in you can specify the column name as regular expression as well.

Comment: the link for colRegex is https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex.html

Answer (score 1):

This sample code does what you want:

```
hello_cols = []

for col in df.columns:
  if(('index' in col) or ('hello' in col)):
    hello_cols.append(col)

df.select(*hello_cols)
```

Comment: Thanks, i fixed an error in your code and it worked.

Comment: @Antonio Manrique
 You're right. I wrote my code in python 2.7. Please accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I will give it an upvote ! But i've found myself a better option for what i am doing, i'll post it as an answer and accept it. But thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

i used Manrique answer and improvised.

sel_cols = [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith("colName")]

df = df.select('*', *(F.col(x).alias('rename_text' + x) for x in sel_cols))